# Submit form array with Vue to Laravel

Tags: forms, laravel, vuejs2, axios, laravel-5.4

Before I started using Vue I had a simple form that would update 1 value on 1 column @ 1 request at a time. Now I am using Vue and my form has a new 'middle' button that is being used to build up an array of items to submit 1 request to update multiple columns dynamically.

Problem is now that prevent default is enabled, my original form submission no longer works and I need to either submit the request with Vue or is there a way to re-enable default action on a button? This would be great.

```
<form @submit.prevent="newbutton">

// new button
<button @click="newbutton"></button>

// original button
<button @click="submit" :id="{{ $element->id }}></button> // @submit.enableDefault ??
```

Answer (score 1):

The prevent is just a helper method on the @submit.  To allow this variance you will need to move the logic into your newbutton method

```
// in template remove prevent
<form @submit="newbutton" action="/where-this-should-post">

// in script move logic to your newbutton method
methods {
  newbutton(event) {
    if (formNotValid) {
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting! How do you test for formNotValid? Thanks for the help!

Comment: No need to test for formNotValid, just fired event.preventDefault(); in the middle button and took out @submit.prevent and it works nearly as expected. Problem now is binding the vue data to form submission

Comment: It can be a computed property or you can create a function and call that.  It will look at all the data in your form and make sure it is OK to send it along.

Comment: Also is not required to have that is just easier in spas to knock that out on front end

Comment: @Dazzle did you need anything else on this one?

Comment: I'm trying but no success. I have a data object built up from select tags but the v-model on tags does not match the data object I am building with the select options. How can I attach data: { items = {} // to methods: { submit() { axios({ method: 'post', url: '/post/ . id, data: vm.$data.items)} ? right now I am trying to return $request in my Laravel controller is empty, but I get a 200 status code and the Headers section of networking debugging shows the items property as expected but its not in the request

Comment: Ok, that sounds like a separate issue where you are not settings the data using vm.set ([] is not reactive in vue).  You should first see if submitting this works with moving event.preventDefault as described above by just posting up something like string 'foo' using axios.  If the data gets there then create a new question with the new issue, will help others in the future.  Also always best to add a jsfiddle with example.

Comment: I am setting the data with vm.$set in the middle button but not sure how I can incl a data object to send along with my request.. still looking

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136264/discussion-between-austio-and-dazzle).